# Is it OK to casually flag comments as obsolete?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

Especially under the lower-quality questions there’s a lot of comments that request further information about the question et cetera. To these the question author will often reply with several comments more instead of editing. I usually edit to add the details to the question, which makes the comments redundant. Is it OK to mark them as obsolete & to be deleted?

The scenario I mentioned is not the only one – another one is when somebody comments that a link has expired, there’s a typo or something like that. After editing the comment is not needed anymore, can it be marked as obsolete? On one hand I’m not really comfortable flagging so many comments (it feels like abuse), on the other hand having many comments usually clutters the thread, especially if the comments are not really needed anymore.

Comment: Yes, and please do!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's exactly what the `obsolete` flag is *for*. Flag away!

Comments are, by their very nature, transitional.  Flagging helps keep them under control and tidied up.  Note that if a comment has been flagged multiple times, it'll be auto-removed, so you are not overly burdening the janito<kbd>CTRL+W</kbd>moderators when flagging comments, provided we all do our bit.