# No-longer-valid comments that were responded to

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

Sometimes I put a comment on a post for a problem that is then fixed and the OP gives a comment to tell me so.  It seems strange to delete the comment and leave his comment hanging there, but since my comment is no longer applicable, shouldn't it go?  Is there something else I should do?

Comment: Flag as obsolete?

Comment: Do you need to treasure your comment?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251294/should-the-comment-be-removed-once-it-becomes-obsolete http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182684/flagging-obsolete-comment-conversations http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32444/is-it-appropriate-to-delete-my-comment

Comment: @random: My only problem with deleting my comment is that it leaves the OP's comment dangling.  I have no reason to treasure it if it is no longer applicable.

Comment: Delete your comment, flag theirs as obsolete. That's all

Comment: @random: Thank you.