# Does a user have the right to not engage in discussion that have been addressed and can lead to heated exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, account-suspension

When a user receives comments that ask for things that have already been clarified in the post or the previous ones, and often in an provocative attitude, does the user have the right to not engage?

Can a moderator suspend a user for not engaging in such discussion?

Comment: This sounds a lot like it's not a hypothetical.  Would you care to elaborate on the specific circumstances?

Comment: You always have the right to walk away from an argument.  Seems like a wise thing to do compared to the alternative and I can't imagine why you would get suspended for choosing peace

Comment: @Ryan There are multiple situations where that have happened. It is not easy to elaborate the details. I have too many similar experiences before this one, and it only ended up in success once. At this moment, it is up to whether you could believe in my judgement

Comment: The answer to this question, as written, is too obvious to merit the question being asked and answered.  Therefore, without more details, it cannot be reasonably answered.

Comment: Well, Tim, the problem we have is that a large percentage of the people who post on Meta Stack Exchange about problems with moderation are ... not providing the whole truth. At the very least, they are describing things from their own point of view, but *many* omit very pertinent parts of the situation, or even outright lie in an attempt to get people to agree with them, for whatever reason. We're not saying you're doing so, just that your question is *quite* light on details. But, based *only* on the information you've provided, @JourneymanGeekOnStrike has the right answer in their comment.

Comment: If you have a problem with something that an elected moderator (or staff) has done, which would include any suspension, then you should use the "contact"/"contact us" link in the footer of every page to privately explain the issues and request that Stack Exchange staff take a look at the situation. That's, really, the primary effective recourse.

Comment: @Makyen I stopped using StackExchange for a while, because some moderators abused their powers, which mentally tortured me, and the SE staff didn't help at all except once.

Comment: @RyanM There have been a number of meaningful [updates](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct/) to what once was *"obvious"*, whereas likely involved details remain adequately [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191296/what-to-do-if-i-disagree-with-the-handling-of-my-flag) elsewhere. Maybe the plain question *without* the details is the one that merits clarifying what happened to "stop participating".

Comment: Pretty sure there's something else behind this question. Was the intent to indirectly show that you still have a bone to pick with moderators?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anything wrong that a user prefers upvoting over accepting replies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390537/is-there-anything-wrong-that-a-user-prefers-upvoting-over-accepting-replies)

Comment: Now we have to speculate. It could be [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21105/were-the-names-of-the-10-months-in-the-ancient-roman-calendar-originally-named-a) (initially moved to chat. And/or the cluster of [more than 20 questions](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/1100/tim?tab=questions&sort=newest) within the last 6-8 weeks) or even [this MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390537/is-there-anything-wrong-that-a-user-prefers-upvoting-over-accepting-replies).

Answer (score 19):

You always have the right to walk away from an argument. In many cases, to quote *[WarGames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames)*. "[The only way to win is not to play at all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpmGXeAtWUw)". And quite often walking away from an argument *is* the right thing to do.

You can't win everyone over and if you feel provoked or *know* someone is trying to provoke you the best thing to do is to leave it and walk away.

And if a place isn't working for you and you constantly get in trouble, or worse, you're frustrated and you're 'mentally tortured' - even if a place isn't toxic, it can be toxic for *you* and there's nothing wrong in finding and looking for a place that better fits your needs.

Answer (score 16):

> Can a moderator suspend a user for not engaging in such discussion?

Moderators don't suspend for **not** doing something.

We have no authority over your *life*. At any time you can decide (or be forced to) not participate here. You may need to go to work, your internet might break down, you maybe in a "no phones" zone, your mom might call you to dinner, maybe your wife distracts you with something more fun, maybe you are just bored and go to sleep. Not participating here is not a reason to do *anything* from our side.

Comment: "don't suspend for not doing something" - Well, but SE does. Remember Monica? She didn't do something, and as result all hell broke loose.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack They did not suspend her for being absent or silent. The disagreement was about something she actively did. I am firmly on Monica's side on that topic, because I think what she did was the best, most respectful compromise to all involved sides, but it certainly was about *participation* here, not about non-participation.

Comment: Just in case that isn't clear: If someone writes "you stupid idiot", we don't suspend them for "*not* being polite", we suspend them for actively "being rude". We would never suspend someone for not having said anything at all.

Comment: That's not what I heard or understand. From what I saw, she was un-modded for declaring she will not sign the new mod agreement. Was there more to it?

Comment: I will not talk about the details, since the whole topic has been deemed unspeakable and punishable on this site by our overlords. Again, I don't agree, but what happened, happened because of actions, not because of being absent or disengaging. Also, she was not suspended as a user by a mod, what this question is about. Mods are held to different standards, an things *can* happen to mods, because of inaction or absence. For example if you don't log in for 6 months, you will probably lose your mod status. And I think that is fine, but not part of this question.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack - Don't believe everything you "hear" ("hearing" is not the same as knowing; we "hear" through filters already in place) and clearly you don't understand what happened. Why stir the pot? It's already boiling over.

Comment: @anongoodnurse true, but Monica case is already cold, and this new one is worse in some ways, and different enough IMO. Anyway, got my answer.